Altium v24.10.1 - Is there a way to connect a github repo to an Altium 365 workspace?
An engineering org that I'm a part of has been using Github repos to store all their Altium pcb projects. I thought it would be a good idea to use Altium 365 instead since it's more convenient to use, but first we have to get their previous Altium projects from the repos onto 365.
Is there a guide out there on how to do this?

Assuming that you have 365 setup correctly and you have your cloud setup in altium...
Just download the repo and open the project in altium, then right click on the project and select save to server. You'll have to do this for each project
